# Is it right having ViewControllers with a lots of code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, design-patterns

I'm still quite new to Cocoa and Objective-C (<1 year). My App now has some 50+ classes, but some of the ViewControllers get quite crowded with code, like 700 lines or more.

My question is: is it fine to have a "large" ViewController or are there patterns for splitting up code into fractions? A lots of the code is implementing delegate methods, thats why I don't have an idea how to move it away.

I know, I can structurize with pragma marks though.

Thanks for any input.

EDIT (Dec 2013): there is a [great article from Chris Eidhof](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/lighter-view-controllers.html) of objc.io regarding this subject. He also talked about that subject on Macoun 2013/Frankfurt. Separating out the UITableView protocols are a great pattern.

EDIT2  There are also 2 videos on [NSScreencast](http://www.nsscreencast.com) explaining concepts of refactoring ViewController (episode #102 and #103).

Comment: +1 Great question. Good to know that there are people who care.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers - much appreciated! It's almost impossible to choose the 'right' answer though. For myself, if have identified, that I havn't been strict enough in separating the model-code out of the VC. But also I will learn the concept of categories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the most common causes of large view controllers that I have seen, is lack of separation b/w Model and Controller in MVC architecture. In other words, are you handling your data in your view controllers?

If yes, rip out the model component from VC and put it into separate class. This will also force your thinking towards a better design.

For reference, In View Controller:

- Handling of all changes in the UIView and the UI elements contained within.
- All animation, transitions and CALayer operations.

In Model:

- All processing of data, including sorting, conversion, storage, etc.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, 700 lines is not (yet) huge for iOS code, I've seen and handled much worse. Of course, if all your VCs are this big, you have a problem.

You should definitely use and abuse `#pragma mark`, it's **very** useful under Xcode at least.

Then if you find you got too much code in one file, you can extract functionality to classes or categories, as better fits.

Creating classes can be very rewarding in the long term to manage recurring tasks in projects (ie connecting to webservice, parsing XML/JSON, interacting with SQLlite, logging, etc...). If you are doing recurrent iOS programming, you can create a 'common' library of useful code that way.

Creating categories, especially on `UIViewController` can help reducing *boilerplate* code that takes a lot of place. You can (and probably should) also create a common base `UIViewController` for your app, that will handle stuff like rotation, maybe logging, navigation, etc... in a centralized part of the code.

Comment: True, I have a 1300 line VC, and it is not bad at all since most of the lines are just custom animations etc.. I think it depends on what kind of methods and dependencies the class has.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to identify what your ViewController is really doing.

If you can separate some concerns you can move them to classes of their own. Find out which properties and ivars are used by the viewControllers methods. If you can find a subset of functions, that use a common subset of ivars/properties, these together are very likely to become a class of their own. The controller would then own such a new class and delegate work to this.

If your ViewController is managing some sort of state, eg. you find the same switch statement or if-chain in 2 or more methods the STATE pattern could make your VC much more readable. But basically you could use any pattern that helps to reduce the VCs responsibilities.

IMHO the ViewController is the place were you would connect the model to the views. Propagating model changes into views and handling user interaction with the views are the only things, that should happen there. All other responsibilities, like calculation, network transfer, parsing, validation... should happen in different classes the VC uses.

You might like the book Clean Code by Robert C. Martin. He explores in depth how code could be structured to increase it's readability and reusability.

Answer (score 2):

You can distribute the code using categories depending on the functionality. Refer http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html

Comment: While this might improve code readability, it does not improve the reusability and dose not help to separate concerns. If you can split the VC in naturally separate categories, why not split it in different classes?

Comment: The whole point of splitting the code into categories is because the methods become a part of the class type. Splitting into different classes is a completely different concept. If the  code is insanely big, it is better to split it into categories.

Comment: Yes I know, and I get your point. And I agree that it is better to split in categories, then just leaving it so. But the best way is to create separate classes. Each class gets the properties  it needs to do it's work. Splitting the code into multiple categories leads to one big class, that has multiple responsibilities. That leads to [MAGIC PUSHBUTTON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_pushbutton) or [GOD OBJECT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)

Answer (score 0):

Prefer the use of NSObject class to manage part of your view controller functions. Main reasons code is more clear and easier to debug

Comment: Care to elaborate? I have no idea what you're suggesting here.